# R: rows get filled with NA after removing other rows

Tags: r, subset

I cannot even begin to figure out what is happening here except that rows filled with `NA`s are getting added to my data after I remove some rows.  So I'm just going to walk through what I did.

#### 1. I import a large csv file using data.table::fread for speed purposes:

```
mdata = data.table::fread("~/data.csv")
```

#### 2. I don't like working with data.tables (blasphemy, I know), so I convert mdata to a data.frame:

```
class(mdata) = "data.frame"
```

#### 3.  I convert my `clusterID` column to a factor:

```
mdata$cluster_ID = as.factor(mdata$cluster_ID)
```

#### 4. For the question, I check `clusterID`:

```
plyr::count(mdata$cluster_ID)

       x freq

1      1 6100
2      2 1484
3      3 1925

...

38    29 3868
```

and the number of rows:

```
original_n = nrow(mdata)
original_n
[1] 99412
```

#### 5. Several text columns have cells that should be `NA`s but are just empty text (eg they are like this `x = ""` instead of this `x = NA`).  So I convert them to `NA`s:

```
mdata[mdata==""] = NA
```

So far so good.

#### 6. I go to remove rows from the data I need to exclude from analysis:

```
mdata = mdata[mdata$var1 != "this",]  #should remove 218 rows

nrow(mdata)
[1] 99194
original_n - nrow(mdata)
[1] 218
```

So it removed the correct number of rows.  Good.

However, when I check the `clusterID` column, there are 174 `NA`s that didn't use to be there and, when you look at `clusterID` 3 you see it has decreased by 224 (more than the number of rows I removed).

```
plyr::count(mdata$cluster_ID)

       x freq

1      1 6083
2      2 1484
3      3 1701

...

38    29 3868
39  <NA>  174
```

#### What I've tried

I've tried using other import methods (`readr:read_csv`; base `read.csv`; opening in Excel, saving as .xlsx, and importing with `readxl::read_excel`), but none of those worked.

I checked what the `NA` rows look like, and they're all just a bunch of `NA`s:

```
temp = mdata[is.na(mdata$cluster_ID), ]
mean(!is.na(temp))
[1] 0
```

As best as I can tell, somehow a bunch of rows are just getting changed to `NA`s when I remove rows with `mdata = mdata[mdata$var1 != "this",]`.  I've checked, and it looks like they are the same rows each time.

For confidentiality reasons, I can't post the data but any help figuring out why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

If it makes any difference I'm running Microsoft R Open:

```
Sys.info()
                                                                                          sysname 
                                                                                         "Darwin" 
                                                                                          release 
                                                                                         "17.4.0" 
                                                                                          version 
"Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0: Sun Dec 17 09:19:54 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.41.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64" 
                                                                        machine 
                                                                                         "x86_64" 

sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readxl_1.0.0     readr_1.1.1      RevoUtils_10.0.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.14        audio_0.1-5         assertthat_0.2.0    utf8_1.1.2          crayon_1.3.4       
 [6] cellranger_1.1.0    plyr_1.8.4          R6_2.2.2            magrittr_1.5        pillar_1.0.1       
[11] cli_1.0.0           rlang_0.1.6         stringi_1.1.6       rstudioapi_0.7      data.table_1.10.4-3
[16] tools_3.4.3         stringr_1.2.0       hms_0.4.0           yaml_2.1.16         compiler_3.4.3     
[21] pkgconfig_2.0.1     beepr_1.2           tibble_1.4.1
```

Comment: Use `which()`: `mdata = mdata[which(mdata$var1 != "this"),]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The `mdata$var1` had `NA`s in it, so when I did `mdata = mdata[mdata$var1 != "this",]` all of the rows where `mdata$var1` was `NA` got converted to `NA`s.  Maybe it's just me, but this seems like a *really* bad way to handle subsetting when the selection variable is missing.

Comment: To expand on this, `NA` are contagious in R, most functions will return `NA` if any argument is `NA` without explicitly being specified otherwise.  See `x <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, NA), b = 4:6)`. I think you rightly expect `x$a != 1` to return  `FALSE  TRUE    NA`. I think you also rightly expect `x[c(0, 1, NA), ]` to return a row with `NA`, and therefore so should `x[x$a != 1, ]`. The way to avoid this is to use `which`, as in `x[which(x$a != 1), ]`.